# undefined method `friendly' getting error from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I have work on project with ruby on rails and i want to use friendly_id gem. When I install friendly_id gem in my project then add following code according to instructions.

controller:

```
def show
    @group = Group.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Model:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged]
```

I am using rails version 3.2.11 and friendly_id gem is 4.0.0

Getting error in controller. i do not understand why its happening.

error:

```
undefined method `slug' for #<Group:0x000000092ac228>
```

**Update**:

Previous issue solve with restart server and migrating database.

but it generates new issue `Couldn't find group with id=new-demo-group`

Comment: have you add/migrate slug field to the model?

Comment: Yes !! I have added slug field for Group model.

Comment: have you restart the server too?

Comment: Yeah! its works now after restart server but it shows error `Couldn't find group with id=new-demo-group`.

Comment: if you add friendly id to existing model you also need to resave it all to generate slug example `User.find_each(&:save)`

Comment: I have try this code but still same issue.

Comment: did you run that code in your server console?

Comment: I have add this code in create method of  group controller and create new group but it shows  issue regarding ID.

Comment: do you try using `use: :slugged` instead of `use: [:slugged]`?

Comment: @Thanh I have try this but it shows same issue. `Couldn't find group with id=new-demo-group`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to update the records that are already created, in your case that would be (Group model), as docs says:

> If you're adding FriendlyId to an existing app and need to generate
>   slugs for existing users, do this from the console, runner, or add a
>   Rake task:

```
Group.find_each(&:save)
```

**Rails console**

Open terminal on the app root and run (-e is the environment)

```
rails console -e production
```

You should get a similar output to this (I added the command to run):

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 5389
Loading production environment (Rails 5.1.5)
2.5.1 :001 > Group.find_each(&:save)
```

**Rails runner**

Open terminal on the app root and run (-e is the environment)

```
rails runner -e production "Group.find_each(&:save)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but can you explain how to do from console, runner, or add a rake task to Group.find_each(&:save).